# C: Passing two dimensional arrays by reference in a function and how to use them inside

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to have a function which does the following:

```
int doFunction(int* nIndex)
{

  //nIndex is a 2-D array of any size.
// I would like to fill this array inside this function.
//Eg: in nIndex[2][3], i would like to put 5.

}

int result;
int myIndex[5][6];

result = doFunction(myIndex);
```

could someone please help me with two things:
1. is the syntax above correct for function definition requiring a 2-d array of any size?
2. is the syntax ok for when i pass myIndex into the function?
3. How to i fill the array in the function, or how do i access its fields?

thanks.

Comment: I'm sure it's a duplicate of something. Possibly (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404232/how-do-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-two-dimensional-array-to-a-function) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659304/passing-two-dimensional-array-to-a-function-by-refrence-c-programming), (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548753/passing-a-multidimensional-variable-length-array-to-a-function) and tons of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaration and definition:

```
// either void fill_arr(int arr[][5]) or:
void fill_arr(int arr[3][5])
{
    int i j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = 42;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling:

```
int arr[3][5];
fill_arr(arr);
```

Comment: This works of course, but you are limited to int[3][5] or at most int[][5]...

Comment: thanks, but i would like both the array sizes to be variable

Comment: @Sunny then, pass in another parameter `len` to be the range of the inner subscription. then access `arr[i][j]` as `arr+(i*len)+j`. If you hate doing so, use [`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html)

Comment: @Sunny What do you mean by variable? Do you want an array of pointers to mallocated memory?